# Difference between mel-spectrogram and an MFCC

Tags: spectrogram, mfcc, librosa

I'm using the librosa library to convert music segments into mel-spectrograms to use as inputs for my neural network, as shown in the docs [here](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html).

How is this different from [MFCCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum), if at all? Are there any advantages or disadvantages to using either?

Answer (score 19):

To get MFCC, compute the DCT on the mel-spectrogram. The mel-spectrogram is often log-scaled before.

MFCC is a very compressible representation, often using just 20 or 13 coefficients instead of 32-64 bands in Mel spectrogram. The MFCC is a bit more decorrelarated, which can be beneficial with linear models like Gaussian Mixture Models. With lots of data and strong classifiers like Convolutional Neural Networks, mel-spectrogram can often perform better.

Mel-spectrograms are considerably easier to understand when plotted, as they are a time-frequency representation that maps well to the observed sounds. MFCCs on the other hand are quite tricky to interpret.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose, jonnor's answer is not exactly correct. There are two steps:
1. Take logs of Mel spectrogram.
2. Compute DCT on logs.
Moreover, taking logs seems to be "the main part" for training NN: https://qr.ae/TWtPLD

Answer (score 4):

A key difference is that the mel-spectrogram has the semantics of a spectrum, whereas MFCC in a sense is a 'spectrum of a spectrum'. The real question is thus: What is the purpose of applying the DCT to the mel-spectrogram, which has good answers [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-do-i-interpret-the-dct-step-in-the-mfcc-extraction-process) and [there](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15938/is-this-a-correct-interpretation-of-the-dct-step-in-mfcc-calculation/15945#15945).

---

Note that in the meantime librosa also has a [`mfcc`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) function. And looking at [its implementation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/_modules/librosa/feature/spectral.html#mfcc) basically confirms that it is

1. calling [`melspectrogram`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html),
2. converting its output to logs (via `power_to_db`),
3. taking the DCT of the frequencies, as if they were a signal,
4. truncating the new 'spectrum of spectrum' after the first `n_mfcc` coefficients.